# Cable required for extended screen

Tags: macbook-pro

I would like to use my MacBook Air as a extended screen for my iMac, both are running OSX 10.9.2 and both have lightning connectors. What lead should I buy?
Kind Regards

Answer (score 1):

Apple does not allow Target Display Mode on anything but a few select iMac models. You can see the complete list on [Apples's TDM Support Page](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3924?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US).

There may be a third party solution but I am not aware of any.